# How do I make Uploadify work with CakePHP AND the Media Plugin?

Tags: cakephp, plugins, media, uploadify

There are lots of tutorials out there for using Uploadify with CakePHP or CakePHP with the Media Plugin, but has anyone actually got Uploadify to work WITH the Media Plugin? These are two of the best options available, why is it so hard to make them work together? If you have can you show some code?

Comment: upvoted because I've been wondering the same thing for a while now...

Comment: I'm going to be working on it within the next couple weeks. Once I get it figured out I'll post the solution. In the meantime anyone who knows the answer... feel free to help. Thanks!

Comment: I'm working on this too...
I would like to use uploadify to upload an image with progressbar and media plugin to make thumbnail and add data in the DB.
So if I find a solution...

Comment: Just a note. I completely gave up on this and used a jQuery HTML5 uploader and just ignored IE. I'm going to leave the question here in hopes that someday someone can answer it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This plugin is born because uploadify is really hard to implement on cakephp media plugin.

http://pixelcone.com/fileuploader/